# Which are the good open source libraries for Collective Intelligence in .net/java?

Tags: java, .net, collective-intelligence

Or any open source project which utilize collective intelligence extensively?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new book out from Manning, ["Collective Intelligence in Action"](http://www.manning.com/alag/). There are also code samples available written in Java. I also recommend the Toby Segaran book. Coming from a Java background I was able to follow the Python code without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the book [Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) by Toby Segaran. It covers lots of topics, such as how Amazon generates recommendations etc etc. There's lots of source code in the book written in Python, which should be easy to port to Java/.Net

Answer (score 1):

look up weka (java) and the Datamining book by Franke and Witten