# Looking for collective intelligence .Net / C# resources

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, cluster-analysis, collective-intelligence

Firstly, I realise that this is a very similar question to this one: [Which are the good open source libraries for Collective Intelligence in .net/java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345982/which-are-the-good-open-source-libraries-for-collective-intelligence-in-net-java)

... but all the answers to that one were Java centric so I am asking again, this time looking more for .Net (idealy C#) ideas.

A little background; I recently read [Toby Segran's excellent book on CI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325), and I just got hold of [Satnam Alag's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988312) (which I am sure is also excellent, but I have only just opened it). These are Python and Java centric, I don't have any trouble reading the code samples, but as I am a C# developer it would be fun to play with some of these ideas in my native language. I've had a search of the web and SO and not come up with too much. In a way this is great news, maybe I could port something to .Net (suggestions welcome), but I'd also really like to take a look at any existing projects before I do this.

So, are there an CI fans out there working in .Net with OS projects, have I missed some glaringly obvious and interesting books/sites/blogs?

I realise CI is a pretty broad field, so to narrow it down a little I am primarily interested in the clustering / prediction /recommendations areas, but am open to other ideas.

**Edit**: Just spotted this book about to be published by Manning which may interest CI fans: [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](http://www.manning.com/marmanis/).

**Edit** Clarification in response to comment by Moose; what I am looking for really is libraries, frameworks or larger-scale projects (idealy OS) that use CI techniques with .Net. Code samples are great, but as Moose said in his comment it is easy enough to take Java examples and port them. For example, there is an interesting looking project written in Java called [WEKA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weka_%28machine_learning%29), there is no reason I can't use this and experiment with it, I was just curious to know if there were similar things going on in .Net. I have just been browsing info on [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) and I see that there is a C# port of that, so that's a start... are there any more out there?

**Edit** This is not C#, but it is .Net; Robert Pickering has started collection F# CI resources [here](http://github.com/robertpi/fscollintelli/tree/master). Looks interesting, but I'm still looking for C# info too.

Comment: "These are Python and Java centric, I don't have any trouble reading the code samples, but as I am a C# developer it would be fun to play with some of these ideas in my native language." -- If you can read the examples, the best way to learn is to port them to C#, at least for me.

Comment: Agree. Thats why I said "maybe I could port something", but I want to do a survey of what is out there first, if something already exists I'd rather contribute to that or work on something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Research ( full disclosure: I work at Microsoft, though not in the group that released this tool ) has just released a machine learning library in .NET called Infer.NET.

[link text](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/default.aspx)
You might want to check it out.

Comment: Yep, saw this last week, very interesting.

Comment: But you cannot use it in commercial applications: "At this time, commercial use of Infer.NET is limited to Microsoft. No other commercial licenses are available." http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Here's a link for a slope one predictor for rating-based collaborative filtering:

[C# Implementation of Slope One](http://www.cnblogs.com/kuber/articles/SlopeOne_CSharp.html)

Answer (score 4):

This library has:

**Supervised**

- Perceptron
- Kernel Perceptron
- KNN
- Decision Trees

**Unsupervised**

- Hierarchical Clustering
- KMeans

It is called [Machine Learning for .NET](http://machine.codeplex.com).